# Как использовать JS фреймворки с обычным php приложением?

Tags: javascript, php, npm

Я в основном на работе кодил на php.
В принципе само приложение обычное php + mysql + js для всяких ajax.
Всё написано с нуля, без фреймворков.

Я уже долгое время смотрю в сторону новшеств в javascript и как я понял, всё новое сделано для nodejs.
Не буду много писать, как пример react. Открыл документацию, а там примеры кода для работы под nodejs.

А я работаю с обычным umd который запускается в браузере.

Объясните мне как начать использовать какой либо фреймворк JS с обычным php приложением?
Как подключить туда npm?
Как сделать туда webpack?

Добавлю, что фреймворк php не использую, обычный apache и var/www/app директория.

Я в этом не понимаю, хочу пробовать использовать js фреймворки.
Надеюсь я не замудрил и вопрос понятен.

Comment: Сейчас на многих хостингах Nodejs установлен и работает по умолчанию, потому что довольно много CMS включают средства упаковки и оптимизации CSS и JS файлов, написанные на JS и запускаемые из PHP как обычные CLI команды практически так же как запускаются программы на PHP (типа php -f имя файла.php). То есть самый примитивный вариант - запустить выполнение JS файла в nodejs, перехватить выход и обработать его в PHP.

Comment: Вот пример:
создайте файл test.js добавьте строку console.log("hello world");
создайте файл test.php и добавьте в него строку echo exec("nodejs test.js"), "\n";
Далее в этой же папке выполните команду php -f test.php. У меня выводится строка "hello world", потому что у меня установлен nodejs и запускается одноименно.

Comment: для РНР разницы **вообще** никакой. все абсолютно то же самое.  npm и  webpack к РНР отношения не имеют, ставить как обычно

Comment: Если не возиться с SSR, то все эти js-фреймворки работают строго в пределах браузера. Для сервера это всего лишь какая-то кучка статических js-файлов, и у PHP нет вообще никакого дела до этих файлов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте начать с [Alpine.js](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/blob/master/README.ru.md). Она очень близка к Vue, только не требует Node. Можно рассматривать как современную замену jQuery. Рискну дать ссылку на [свой сайт](https://maxsite.org/category/alpine), где я публикую статьи о том, как использовать Альпину. Кроме этого есть такой проект для Laravel  - [livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/quickstart), где используется Alpine.js в качестве основного js-фреймворка. Вы можете просто попробовать что-то сделать с помощью Альпины, поскольку это просто и не потребует дополнительных зависимостей, потом уже решите стоит ли переходить на большие js-фреймворки.

Comment: обязательный https://xkcd.ru/927/

Comment: Спасибо за прекоммендацию, обязательно попробую. Хорошее решение с чего можно начать.

Но вопрос как тогда использоваться php с nodejs у меня остался.